# Preload.js send an arror sometimes about the blob url

Tags: javascript, preload

I'm used to work with preload.js but I have this curious error since today and I don't know where it comes form. The fact is that it appears or not randomly when I load my page.

Here's how I declare my queue :

```
var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue()
```

[image]

Does anyone know what this is ? Thank you very much

Comment: It appears that it cames directly from my preload.js lib ?